# AWK selecting rows using function variable

Tags: function, awk

I have a (probably) simple query re: AWK. I am building a function which is using the function defined variable as filter to select my rows

```
function myfc
 br=$1
 echo $br
 awk '{$2=="$br"}' infile > outfile
myfc ZZ
```

so my `myfc` function should select all rows from $2 = ZZ. But does not. The `echo $br` does return ZZ but the `{$2=="$br"}` does not seem to select the desired rows. I have tried several versions of adding / deleting quotes from `{$2=="$br"}` but to no avail.

any hints for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what shell you are using, but in basic sh:

```
function myfc { awk -v br=$1 '$2==br { print "Hi " $2 " and " $1 }'; }
```

detects when field 2 is the value given as an argument to myfc; so the following:

```
printf "t zz\ns yy\nu aa\n" | myfc zz
```

produces:

```
Hi zz and t
```

So, to match your use case:

```
myfc ZZ < infile > outfile
```

should do the trick.

Comment: Many thanks for the elements of answer mevets - i'm working on a Linux server. I want to select from 'infile' rows corresponding equal to 'ZZ', then repeat the for the other groups i have in col $2. so instead od writing the code n times i thought of writing a function that i would call n times. i will get as many outfile (I'll rename them outfile&br) as I have groups in $2. Apologie sif not clear.

Comment: mainly i don't know how to call a string when i write my condition $2==

Comment: You re a star mevets!!! as beginner in sh scripting i was able to teak my code and make it work using your hints! I was on that for hours before deciding to ask the community. Many thanks Mevets!!!

Comment: 1) make it `br="$1"` to be robust (work even when `$1` contains globbing chars, `$`, spaces, etc.), 2) `function myfc {` is nonportable, use `myfc () {` instead, 3) add an optional file name and then it'll work even if called on a file rather than from a pipe - `myfc() { awk -v br="$1" '$2==br { print "Hi " $2 " and " $1 }' "${@:--}"'; }`